Replace or remove and add new session cookies
I have to apply hmac on the cookies for a vb.net application.
I see that one of the best proposition for this is applying on the Global.asax.vb.
After a few tries I could add the cookies with this code:
    Sub Session_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Fires when the session is started
        Dim context As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current
        Dim cookies As HttpCookieCollection = context.Request.Cookies
        For Each cookie As String In cookies.AllKeys
            Dim currentCookie As HttpCookie = cookies(cookie)
            Dim hmac As String = CalculateHMAC(currentCookie.Value, "secretKey")
            Dim newCookie As New HttpCookie(cookie, currentCookie.Value & ":" & hmac)
            context.Response.SetCookie(newCookie)
        Next
    End Sub

    Function CalculateHMAC(ByVal message As String, ByVal key As String) As String
        Dim encoding As New ASCIIEncoding()
        Dim keyByte() As Byte = encoding.GetBytes(key)
        Dim messageBytes() As Byte = encoding.GetBytes(message)
        Dim hmacsha As New HMACSHA256(keyByte)
        Dim hashmessage() As Byte = hmacsha.ComputeHash(messageBytes)
        Return Convert.ToBase64String(hashmessage)
    End Function

BUT the thing is that it duplicates the cookies: original ones with no hmac and the other applies it ok. And also I see that the new cookies, the path is like /webName and the original only /.
I have tried a few things like adding negative expiration, using contex.Response.Remove(cookie) but nothing removes the original ones
            currentCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
            context.Response.SetCookie(newCookie)

Something like this, but nothing works. It seems I almost there! But I cannot figure out
            currentCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
            context.Response.SetCookie(newCookie)

